# How implement bpm:groupAssignees in a task of a workflow in alfresco?

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I need to assign a task to many groups in a alfresco worflow!Can anybody help me with a example?How to modify a model and share-workflow-form-config.xml to suport this option?Thank you in advence!

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is as below.

Alfresco supports concept of group inside group(subgroups).So you can assign task to that particular group and achieve your requirement.

Further more,for creating workflow there are 2 workflow engines which are widely used(activiti and jbpm).You can use any of them.
For creating workflow you will need to create below files.

- Task Model(Defining Properties)
- Process Definition(Defines Workflow)
- Web Client configuration(Displaying properties in UI.It defines forms)
- Context File(For injecting process definition and model file)

For more details on JBPM workflow you can find below link use full.

http://krutikjayswal-alfresco.blogspot.in/2014/04/jbpm-workflow-in-alfresco.html

In above blog, for activiti workflow change will be only in process definition file.

Comment: Can I restrict to assignment of workflow to subgroup automatically?

Comment: Yes you can do that, I did one implementation where assignment to restricted to group name starting with Finance.Your requirement is bit differrent ,but posible

Comment: I have GROUP_1,under that there are 2 subgroup.When ever I assign any workflow to GROUP_1 then it automatically assign to subgroup,I want to Restrict that.Can you give me some Idea.